# I would like to hide menu on desktop but still have it visible on small screen

Tags: navigation, responsive

I have added the code bellow in order to hide the navigation menu from my homepage.

```
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'wpse_210095');
function wpse_210095($menu) {
  if (is_home()) {
   $menu = '';
  }
  return $menu;
}
```

Can please someone help me and let me know what to do to have it back on small screen only. The theme I am using is [wp-spirit01](http://www.template-joomspirit.com/theme-wordpress/theme-01/). I don't have my website live yet.

Comment: What is "desktop"? What is "small screen"? It might be obvious to you, but people can put different meaning into these terms.

Comment: I apologize. Desktop is computer view, small screen is tablet and mobile view.

Comment: Again, this is rather unspecific. What is view? Is it a screen size? Some resolution, say 1920x1080, can be either of three.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about screen size. I am not aware of the exact resolution.

Comment: Copy and pasting from other questions is not much of a research, please first try by yourself and show the code that you have tried to write and you have problems making it work in the way you want to.

Comment: @Zorica Petkovik: Please check media query css for this, I think this is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using a media query. If you don't mind I suggest you to use media query simple.

The exact query will depend on your site structure and how the menu is identified in your code. Before you do that, make sure your navigation will not be hidden as well; most website navigation is within the header of the site.

Please try adding the following CSS code in the `style.css` file of your theme.

```
//Set by given example theme link (http://www.template-joomspirit.com/theme-wordpress/theme-01/)

/*This CSS code apply while screen resolution is less OR 480 px only, you can change min-width value as per your requirement*/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .drop-down span.title_menu {//For menu button, Class set for example only, Please change it with your requirement...
        display: none !important;
    }

    .drop-down ul {//For Navidation, Class set for example only, Please change it with your requirement...
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

OR if your theme doesn't have custom CSS tab add it in your site using the [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) plugin. This plugin is designed to meet the needs of administrators who would like to add their own CSS to their WordPress website.

This should remove the menu on resolutions smaller then *480px*.

Here's some information about media queries that should help:

[CSS TRICKS - Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices)

[CSS TRICKS - Logic in Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries)

[Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[Use CSS media queries for responsiveness](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries)

Hope this helps. Let me know if there is any query/doubts from this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried few different options but it is not working. I have the "menu" bottom showing on a smaller resolution then 760px but when I click on it the menu tabs don't display, just a black menu background.

Comment: I set JFFIDDLE example(http://jsfiddle.net/9rc7f0o0/) for clear solution. This solution is based on your given reference link. Please check it and let me know if there is still you face some issue with describe. If still issue then what did you mean "let me know what to do to have it back on small screen only".